# its a problem while using apt-get install on my ubuntu 14.04 pc

Tags: command-line, apt

its a problem while using apt-get install on my ubuntu 14.04 pc it showing like this:

*root@aneesh-Aspire-E1-471:/home/nart# apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 android-tools-adb : Depends: adb but it is not going to be installed
 android-tools-fastboot : Depends: fastboot but it is not going to be installed
 recordmydesktop:i386 : Depends: libvorbisenc2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).*

Comment: Have you tried running *sudo apt install -f* ?

Comment: The error message states: _"Try `apt-get -f install`"_.    That is a pretty good suggestion.

Comment: Please update your question with output of `apt-cache policy android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot adb fastboot recordmydesktop libvorbisenc2`.

Comment: I already tried apt-get -f install